# problem with delete when multiple columns

Tags: linq, activerecord, subsonic, subsonic3

when deleteing this works:

```
orderitems.Delete(x => x.orderitem_sessionid == transkey);
```

however this does not work

```
orderitem.Delete(x => x.orderitem_sessionid == transkey 
                       && x.orderitem_productid == 6);
```

i get no errors, but nothing is deleted either, i have working code as a substitute of

```
var DeleteableItems = orderitems.All().where(x => x.orderitem_sessionid == transkey 
                                             && x.orderitem_productid = 6);

foreach(var item in DeleteableItems) item.delete;
```

though the above works it still bugs me that this wont work with just nomal delete method, using subsonic 3.0.0.3 and mysql database

thanks

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Have you tried:</strike>

```
orderitem.Delete(x => x.orderitem_sessionid == transkey 
                      && x.orderitem_productid == 6);
```

The last operator in your version is assignment not comparisson.

My answer concerned a typo  but the comments on getting the generated SQL below some might find useful.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: yes sorry the mistake of extra = was a typo when writing out the post
another developer had the problem on his machine, i gave hime the solution as i could not understand why it would not delete, plus time is key ya know.

is there some way i can output the sql that was sent, so i check how it is translated and then take it from there....

thanks

Comment: If SQL Server is the backend, open SQL Profiler from the tools menu of the Management Studio and set up a new trace. Profile the bits you want and check what queries are being fired at your DB. I find writing a unit test I can set a debug point in quite useful. Clear the log then let the unit test go. Your SQL is at the top.